# C++ Templates the complete guide. Assign operator

Tags: c++, templates, operator-keyword, assign

As an example in this book: [http://www.amazon.com/C-Templates-The-Complete-Guide/dp/0201734842](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734842) they have this class:

```
template <typename T> 
class Stack { 
 private: 
 std::deque<T> elems; // elements
 public: 
 void push(T const&); // push element
 void pop(); // pop element
 T top() const; // return top element
 bool empty() const { // return whether the stack is empty
 return elems.empty(); 
 } 
 // assign stack of elements of type T2 
 template <typename T2> 
 Stack<T>& operator= (Stack<T2> const&); 
};
```

And here is the implementation of assign operator:

```
template <typename T> 
 template <typename T2> 
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator= (Stack<T2> const& op2) 
{ 
 if ((void*)this == (void*)&op2) { // assignment to itself?
 return *this; 
 } 
 Stack<T2> tmp(op2); // create a copy of the assigned stack
 elems.clear(); // remove existing elements
 while (!tmp.empty()) { // copy all elements
 elems.push_front(tmp.top()); 
 tmp.pop(); 
 } 
 return *this; 
}
```

And here is some explanation on what that method does:

> Inside the member function you may expect simply to access all
>   necessary data for the assigned stack op2.  However, this stack has a
>   different type (if you instantiate a class template for two different
>   types, you get two  different types), so you are restricted to using
>   the public interface. It follows that the only way to access the
>   elements  is by calling top(). However, each element has to become a
>   top element, then. Thus, a copy of op2 must first be made,  so that
>   the elements are taken from that copy by calling pop().

I am getting confused with this part:

> However, this stack has a
>   different type (if you instantiate a class template for two different
>   types, you get two  different types), so you are restricted to using
>   the public interface.

Does this say that i am allowed ONLY to use public interfases, or i am NOT allowed to use public intefaces?
If it means that i am not allowed to use public interfases, than what is a top() member function? Isn't it a public method?

Comment: More suited to http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It means only allowed to use public method, since `Stack<T>` and `Stack<T2>` are different types, so can't call non-public methods of `Stack<T2>` in `Stack<T>` 's methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, this stack has a different type (if you instantiate a class template for two different types, you get two different types), so you are restricted to using the public interface.

It means that you **should use only public** interface. In fact, if you want to implement the operator= function then you **must use only public** interface.

In case you don't use a public interface you won't be able to access the top() function and that is the only way you can assign the elements of the stack to the other stack.

Yes, **top() is a public function**.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was confused because in a translated book it says exactly that you are not able to use public interfases, that is why i got so confused. Also thank to  songyuanyao

Answer (score 3):

`Stack<T>` and `Stack<T2>` are unrelated type if `T != T2`,
so method of `Stack<T>` cannot use private members of `Stack<T2>` (unless declared as `friend`).

`Stack<T>` (as any other classes) is restricted to use public interface of `Stack<T2>`.